# TIKZ/PGF: Is there a way to programmatically get the opacity of node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Is there a way to dynamically get the opacity of a node? I would like to dynamically modify the opacity of the contents based on the node's opacity.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}


\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{\alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node[visible on=<1->] (qAA) at (0, 0) {
            %{\transparent{\getOpacity+0.01}\color{green}{Print the opacity})
          };
        \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To give more context and the complete code: I am trying to print a tree layer by layer from the bottom. I want the siblings/cousins to be aligned and have few opaque texts. Hence I have some phantom  nodes (by setting the opacity to 0}.

Looks like `\transparent` is interfering with the opacity of the TIKZ. Not sure how to sort this out. I am unable to use `forest` as I plan on customizing the figure with more nodes.

```
\newcommand{\x}{{\color{blue}\ensuremath{x}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
        \node[visible on=<3->] (qAA) at (0, 0) {
                {\transparent{0.3}$g = $}\\$f(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<2->] (qBA) at (-3, -2) {
                {\transparent{0.3}$g = $}\\$f_{0}(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<2->] (qBB) at (3, -2) {
                {\transparent{0}$g = $}\\$f_{1}(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<1->] (qCA) at (-3, -4) {
            {\transparent{0.3}$g = $}\\$f_{0,0}(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<1->] (qCD) at (3, -4) {
            {\transparent{0}$g = $}\\$f_{1,1}(\x)$
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounds like an xy-problem. Can you add some more context of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I have updated the post to give complete context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use transparent text, that can cause more problems than it solves. Instead I would change the text colour by mixing it with the background colour. That's also what beamer does if it uncovers previously dimmed text in overlays.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\newcommand{\x}{{\color{blue}\ensuremath{x}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
        \node[visible on=<3->] (qAA) at (0, 0) {
                \begin{colormixin}{20!parent.bg}$g = $\end{colormixin}\\$f(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<2->] (qBA) at (-3, -2) {
                \begin{colormixin}{20!parent.bg}$g = $\end{colormixin}\\$f_{0}(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<2->] (qBB) at (3, -2) {
                \begin{colormixin}{20!parent.bg}$g = $\end{colormixin}\\$f_{1}(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<1->] (qCA) at (-3, -4) {
                \begin{colormixin}{20!parent.bg}$g = $\end{colormixin}\\$f_{0,0}(\x)$
        };
        \node[visible on=<1->] (qCD) at (3, -4) {
                \begin{colormixin}{20!parent.bg}$g = $\end{colormixin}\\$f_{1,1}(\x)$
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]